# Canvas is clearing on scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, react-hooks, scroll

```
function Component2 ():JSX.Element {
   return (<canvas width="300" height="300></canvas>);
}
export default function Component1(): JSX.Element {
           const scrollToEndRef = useRef(null);
           const [hideScrollEnd, setHideScrollEnd] = useState(false);
      useEffect(() => {
           window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
            if (
                window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >
                document.body.clientHeight - 100
            ) {
                setHideScrollEnd(true);
            } else {
                setHideScrollEnd(false);
            }
            e.stopPropagation();
        }, false);
       }, []);
       return (
               <>
               <Component2/>
               {!hideScrollEnd && (
                    <Button ref={scrollToEndRef}>
                         Scroll to the end
                    </Button>)}
                </>
        );
}
```

If I draw something in canvas. On scroll reaching bottom, "scroll to end" button is hiding as expected. But, canvas is also getting cleared on hiding the button. Anyway to persist the canvas drawing.

Comment: Is this a complete [mcve]? What is editing, drawing, and (*possibly*) "resetting" the `canvas` element? Can you provide a more complete and comprehensive code example sufficient enough to be considered a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change hideScrollEnd, which rerenders your component, including the canvas, that's why it gets cleared, it's a new canvas.

There are 2 possible solutions at least:

1. Move the scroll/hide logic in to the button component itself (means you may need to create your own CustomButton component or something like that)
2. Memoize the Component2

const memoizedComponent2 = useMemo(() => , [...dependencies]);

where `listOfDepencenies` are all the variables which on change should cause the Component2 to rerender.

in your JSX you than use `{memoizedComponent2}` instead of `<Component2/>`

Comment: Use the `memo` HOC to help memoize React components, not the `useMemo` hook.

Comment: Can you provide info as to why use memo over useMemo. Thank you...

Comment: Source is the React docs ([memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)). The `useMemo` hook is for memoizing values, not React components.

Comment: Ok, here is the reference for that https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo.